# How to change color in progress for each div using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have scenario where i want to display progress based on user actions, i have 5 steps that should observe user action and change color accordingly.Onpage load i want to make first div (file selection) active and make a green color once user select a file i want to display file selection completed by changing color to grey and make second div (Validation) active with green color.

1- how we can achieve this task using AngularJs.
2- Do i need to create directive ?

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-arrow">File Selection<span class="arrow-div"></span></div>
    <div class="text-arrow">Validation<span class="arrow-div"></span></div>
    <div class="text-arrow">Upload<span class="arrow-div"></span></div>
    <div class="text-arrow">successful<span class="arrow-div"></span></div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .text-arrow {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:45px;
}
.arrow-div {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.15em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;    /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    background-color:#fff;   /* change background color acc to bg color */ 
    border-left-width: 0.2em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
    left:0.25em;
}
```

script.js

```
$scope.button1 = function() {
 File is selected this should display complete color and 2nd div Validation should be active with green color  
}

$scope.button2 = function() {

}
```

Comment: You want something like [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)?

Comment: You can also have `ng-class` for different style and have a variable in the controller to track the progress.

Comment: Can i get an example i am new to angularjs i will appreciate it

Comment: why don't you just set a class for the active operation div and set specific css on that class?